# Performing a given set of functions for each value of a key in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I have written some lines that, from lists of dictionaries:

- filter some dictionaries,
- perform mathematical operations between them,
- change some of their keys,
- put the resulting dictionaries in a new list,
- sort the dictionaries by a key,
- print them.

All this process is done relatively to two values (1, 2) of a key (item_id).

The question: I was now wondering whether python gives me a way to apply all this to each possible value of the key, or if I will have to copy and past the lines hundreds of times, changing the values.

(these are the first lines I ever wrote (yay!) so I have no clue, but the absence of online information about this makes me feel like I am missing something obvious)

for reference, here is the first double-part of the code, you can laugh at it if you want, ask if the question needs clarification

```
regionA = [dict(is_buy_order=False, price=100, system_id=22, type_id=1, volume_remain=32),
       dict(is_buy_order=True, price=500, system_id=23, type_id=1, volume_remain=33),
       dict(is_buy_order=False, price=10, system_id=24, type_id=2, volume_remain=34)]
regionB = [dict(is_buy_order=False, price=10, system_id=21, type_id=1, volume_remain=31),
       dict(is_buy_order=True, price=100, system_id=25, type_id=2, volume_remain=35),
       dict(is_buy_order=True, price=1000, system_id=26, type_id=2, volume_remain=36)]

total_data = regionA + regionB

# A: filters the two dictionaries relevant for a type id and creates a third dictionary with the profit

# A for 1
type_1max = max((x for x in total_data if x['is_buy_order'] and x['type_id'] == 1), key=lambda x: x['price'])
type_1min = min((x for x in total_data if not x['is_buy_order'] and x['type_id'] == 1), key=lambda x: x['price'])
type_1profit = {key: type_1max[key] - type_1min.get(key, 0) for key in type_1max}

# A for 2:
type_2max = max((x for x in total_data if x['is_buy_order'] and x['type_id'] == 2), key=lambda x: x['price'])
type_2min = min((x for x in total_data if not x['is_buy_order'] and x['type_id'] == 2), key=lambda x: x['price'])
type_2profit = {key: type_2max[key] - type_2min.get(key, 0) for key in type_2max}
```

Comment: I believe what you're missing is a `for` loop…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to first save your regions in a list:

```
list_of_regions = [regionA, regionB, ...]
```

Then you can implement a for loop as such:
(Note we are in range(1 to len(list_all_regions) + 1 because the type_id start at 1, not 0.

```
for i in range(1, len(list_of_all_regions) + 1): 
     type_max = max((x for x in total_data if x['is_buy_order'] and x['type_id'] == i), key=lambda x: x['price']) 
     type_min = min((x for x in total_data if not x['is_buy_order'] and x['type_id'] == i), key=lambda x: x['price']) 
     type_profit = {key: type_max[key] - type_min.get(key, 0) for key in type_max}
```

You will need to store the last line (which is your desired output) somewhere - maybe, a list or other dictionary (of profits) would do. That's up to what you would find best in the problem.

Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks for taking your time to answer a silly question, it is the simplest things that are harder to discover on one's own!